# Clicking on marker to edit marker info in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am making an app that uses google maps and markers, and would like to enable users to long click on map to add a marker, and get a popup that would allow them to name the marker, write a short summary about it, etc. I would also like to enable the users to click on the existing marker and to get a popup with the info they entered previously and that they could edit at any time. At first I tried doing something like this:

```
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SetMarkerInfoActivity.class));

        }
    });
```

I would open new activity when i long click on the map. I added marker code to the SetMarkerInfoActivity:

```
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker))
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                        arg0.longitude))
                        .visible(true));
```

But this seemed like bad solution. Does anyone have some better idea?

Comment: You could open a `dialog` or starts the activity for result to get the information back and insert the new marker in your map `activity`

Comment: I will likely do something like that in the end :) but I was wondering is there some more elegant way that would allow me a simpler solution.

Comment: Use a `dialog` could be the easiest way, if you don't want to use a `dialog` you could use a hidden layout that is shown when you want to add the marker, like a hidden form.

Comment: Cool, thank you, I will use dialog, I looked at some examples and it seems to be the best solution :)

Comment: @Gonzalo Hello Gonzalo, I know I asked this question a looong time ago, but I ended up using the dialog as you suggested. I am cleaning up my profile and I run into this question, and if you answer, I will except it. Thanks for your suggestion and sorry for taking too long to answer